# Ошибка при открытии MAMP

Tags: php

Для задания необходимо написать скрипт для WordPress. Выбрал локальный сервер MAMP. Но при открытии возникает такая ошибка, как ее исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Версия php 8.0.3

Comment: https://translate.google.com.ua/?hl=ru&tab=TT&sl=auto&tl=ru&op=translate

Comment: Я понимаю, что за ошибка, не понимаю как ее исправить

Comment: похоже что не хватает прав для записи в конфигурационный файл